# c# csv file with unwanted CRLFs

Tags: c#, csv, newline

I have a CSV file, and I want to get all the data from index position 1 (The Company Name in the sample data) and compare them too each other.

I am currently using this line of code to read in the CSV file line by line,

```
string[] csvData = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Path");
```

Then I would split them by rows and try to run a code to grab the wanted data like this

```
var comNames = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < csvData.Length; i++){  
    string[] rows = csvData[i].Split(',');  
    comNames.Add(rows[1]);
}
```

But as you all know that won't work for lines 4 and 5 even though it is still the same column. Is there a way for me to delete the CRLF's that are causing this issue so I can make this code work or is there another workaround?

Sample data

```
Serial Number,Company Name,Employee Markme,Description,Leave  
9788189999599,TALES OF SHIVA,Mark,mark,0  
9780099578079,1Q84  
THE  
COMPLETE  
TRILOGY,HARUKI MURAKAMI,Mark,0  
9780198082897,MY KUMAN,Mark,Mark,0
```

Comment: If there is a CRLF within a cell value, the CSV file should have this cell value enclosed in quotes. So basically, this CSV is broken.

Comment: For CSV related stuff I use `CsvHelper` package on Nuget. It takes all the hard work out of all the common issues.

As for your specific issue, you would probably need to normalize text between the commas.

Comment: @leppie would normalizing the text remove the broken CRLF's and add them to one line like how they should be?

Comment: Try: `string[] rows = csvData[i].Trim().Split(',');` - that will remove white space at start and end of string.

Comment: I generally agree with the fact that this is not a valid csv file, but if the number of columns is guarantied for each company row, you could actually parse it column by column.

Comment: @JevonColeman you would probably need a Regex to remove them before commas and the end of the actual line (the hard problem). If you know upfront the expected numbers of columns as Filip Cordas said, then it becomes less hard.

Comment: Also you could look for newline symbol followed by numeric serial number.

Comment: @leppie Sadly the number of columns is not guaranteed but that Regex idea is something I thought of. But wouldnt the Regex just make everything one line? Like the entire code?

Comment: @JevonColeman could you post the text in the picture as actual text so that I can try to write the newline + serialnumber parser?

Comment: There is a way to include commas and linefeeds in a CSV file ... make sure they are in double-quotes. Then you have to make sure that if anything in that column actually *should* contain a double-quote, that it is escaped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below will work if the following assumptions hold true:

1. There is always a serial #
2. There is always a company name
3. There is always a comma before and after the company name
4. The serial # is always exactly 13 digits

#1-3 are required for this solution. You can tweak the RegEx pattern to deal with #4.

```
public List<string> GetListOfCompanies() {
     string data = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\adam\Documents\test.csv");
     var companies = new List<string>();
     var pattern = @"\d{13}";

     //replace the line ending with something unique
     data = data.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "#thisisreallyunique#");

     //find each serial number, and grab the item after it
     foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(data, pattern)) {
        var temp = data.Substring(match.Index); //cut off everything before this match
        var temp2 = temp.Substring(temp.IndexOf(",") + 1); //cut off the serial # and the comma following it
        //at this point we have the company name, plus everything after it
        var company = temp2.Substring(0, temp2.IndexOf(",")); //cut off everything after it
        //oh, and put the spaces back into the company
        company = company.Replace("#thisisreallyunique#", " ");

        companies.Add(company);
     }
     return companies;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution using Superpower parser you could customize it more for your use case. It's a nice library that is really expressive but there are faster solutions. You could write it by hand using the Span to avoid unnecessary memory allocations.

```
using Superpower;
using Superpower.Parsers;
using Superpower.Tokenizers;

var csv = @"Serial Number,Company Name,Employee Markme,Description,Leave
9788189999599,TALES OF SHIVA,Mark,mark,0
9780099578079,1Q84
THE
COMPLETE
TRILOGY,HARUKI MURAKAMI,Mark,0
9780198082897,MY KUMAN,Mark,Mark,0";

var tokenizer = new TokenizerBuilder<CsvToken>()
    .Match(Character.EqualTo(','), CsvToken.Comma)
    .Match(Span.EqualTo("\n\r"), CsvToken.NewLine)
    .Match(Character.EqualTo('\n'), CsvToken.NewLine)
    .Match(Character.EqualTo('\r'), CsvToken.NewLine)
    .Match(Numerics.Integer, CsvToken.Numeric)
    .Match(Span.WithoutAny((char c) => c == '\n' || c == '\r' || c == ',' || (c >= '0' && c <= '9')), CsvToken.String)
    .Build();


//Parses the header will fail if not correct
var Header = from columnName1 in Token.EqualToValue(CsvToken.String, "Serial Number").Then(s => Token.EqualTo(CsvToken.Comma).Value(s))
             from columnName2 in Token.EqualToValue(CsvToken.String, "Company Name").Then(s => Token.EqualTo(CsvToken.Comma).Value(s))
             from columnName3 in Token.EqualToValue(CsvToken.String, "Employee Markme").Then(s => Token.EqualTo(CsvToken.Comma).Value(s))
             from columnName4 in Token.EqualToValue(CsvToken.String, "Description").Then(s => Token.EqualTo(CsvToken.Comma).Value(s))
             from columnName5 in Token.EqualToValue(CsvToken.String, "Leave")
             select new[]
             {
                       columnName1.ToStringValue(),
                       columnName2.ToStringValue(),
                       columnName3.ToStringValue(),
                       columnName4.ToStringValue(),
                       columnName5.ToStringValue()
                   };

//A serial number an integer of 13 digets
var SerialNumber = from number in Token.EqualTo(CsvToken.Numeric)
                   where number.Span.Length == 13
                   select number.ToStringValue();

// An intiger number
var Number = from number in Token.EqualTo(CsvToken.Numeric)
             select number.ToStringValue();

//Text that can hold new lines
var RichText = from values in Token.EqualTo(CsvToken.String)
                              .Or(Token.EqualTo(CsvToken.Numeric))
                              .Or(Token.EqualTo(CsvToken.NewLine)).Many()
               select string.Join("", values.Select(v => v.ToStringValue()));

//Regular text no new lines
var Text = from values in Token.EqualTo(CsvToken.String)
                              .Or(Token.EqualTo(CsvToken.Numeric)).Many()
           select string.Join("", values.Select(v => v.ToStringValue()));

//Parses the row with defined order
var Row = from serialNumber in SerialNumber.Then(s => Token.EqualTo(CsvToken.Comma).Value(s))
          from companyName in RichText.Then(s => Token.EqualTo(CsvToken.Comma).Value(s))
          from employeeMarkme in Text.Then(s => Token.EqualTo(CsvToken.Comma).Value(s))
          from description in Text.Then(s => Token.EqualTo(CsvToken.Comma).Value(s))
          from level in Number
          select new Info
          {
              SerialNumber = serialNumber,
              CompanyName = companyName,
              EmployeeMarkme = employeeMarkme,
              Description = description,
              Level = level
          };

//The actual parser it must have a single row.
var parser = from header in Header.Then(s => Token.EqualTo(CsvToken.NewLine).AtLeastOnce().Value(s))
             from rows in Row.ManyDelimitedBy(Token.EqualTo(CsvToken.NewLine).AtLeastOnce())
             select rows;



var tokens = tokenizer.Tokenize(csv);
var result = parser.Parse(tokens);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result.AsEnumerable()));

Console.ReadLine();
public enum CsvToken
{
    Comma,
    Numeric,
    String,
    NewLine
}

public record Info()
{
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }

    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public string EmployeeMarkme { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string Level { get; set; }
}
```

Here's a dotnet fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/0GX3KN